# Why does this for loop in R repeat multiple times?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm brushing up on my iteration and was doing some for loop exercises from R for Data Science (http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html).  I wrote this for loop to to mimic "99 bottles of beer on the wall":

```
number <- 99:0
for (i in number) {
 print(paste(number, "bottles of beer on the wall"))
}
```

This repeats several times and then stops and I'm not clear why this happens?

**UPDATE**

The 99:0 above is not meant to be 99, which *would* produce the desired results.  The problem with my code was not indexing it properly as outlined in the answer below.

Comment: Did you mean `number <- 99`?

Comment: I just saw your mistake, you need to change into : `print(paste(i, "bottles of beer on the wall"))`. Because you want to print your CURRENT INDEX `i`.

Comment: I understand it's an exercise but I can't resist :-) `sprintf("%i bottles beer on the wall", 99:0)` or `cat(sprintf("%i bottles beer on the wall\n", 99:0))` goes without a loop (well, it's an implicite loop).

Comment: @Uwe, had to look up `sprintf` . . . looks like its a C function, so not very helpful if you don't know C, right?

Comment: @BenG No, `sprintf()` is a base R function. Perhaps, “borrowed” from C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit: @bobbel was first :-)

You need to `print(i)` in your loop and not `print(number)`. The latter is a vector of **all** your numbers and therefore repeats so many times.

```
[1] "5 bottles of beer on the wall"
[1] "4 bottles of beer on the wall"
[1] "3 bottles of beer on the wall"
[1] "2 bottles of beer on the wall"
[1] "1 bottles of beer on the wall"
```

#### Code

```
number <- 5:1
for (i in number) {
    print(paste(i, "bottles of beer on the wall"))
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you want to use `i` inside the loop, not `number`

```
number <- 99:0
for (i in number) {
 print(paste(i, "bottles of beer on the wall"))
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! :-)

Comment: not really @Roman, you got the answer marking. Actually, my comment was the first of all :-)

Answer (score 2):

As commented, this will be repeated 100 times as you forgot to index number in your loop. Didn't you mean...

```
for (i in number) {
  print(paste(number[99-i], "bottles of beer on the wall"))
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but two recommendations: 1) It's generally bad practice to use hardcoded "magic numbers" in your code as they break very easily and 2) This code prints `[1] " bottles of beer on the wall"` in the first line. A possible improvement would be `print(paste(max(number)-i, "bottles of beer on the wall"))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an even more concise version, use `map_dbl()` from `purrr`

```
map_dbl(99:1,print(paste(99:1,'bottles of beer on the wall')))
```

This does return an error: `Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector` but you certainly will get your 99 repetitions counted down!